# How to use Grafana to create graphs with data from Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, grafana

I am new to Grafana and Spring Boot. I am trying to create a Spring Boot application, and use Grafana SimpleJSON Datasource plugin to get data from my Spring Boot APIs and create graphs. I'm following instructions here https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-simple-json-datasource/. Right now I am just hard-coding data into my Spring Boot App.

My question is - Are there other better plugins or approaches people would suggest me to use? SimpleJSON seems to require a very specific format of JSON response, and I don't see too many detailed docs online. Is there any way that I can be more free on my JSON responses of my APIs, and set the parameters needed to plot graphs in Grafana?

Thank you.

Comment: Please don't duplicate your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Micrometer](https://micrometer.io/) with [Spring Boot Actuator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html) framework to expose metric data to a time series database such as Prometheus. Or you can simply write log files, collect them with Promtail and store them in Loki.

At first this might seem like a lot of work to get these things running, but it might be worth it.

I found it surprisingly simple to get the whole monitoring stack running locally with docker-compose:

1. Add services grafana, prometheus, promtail and loki.
2. Configure each of them.

The docker-compose might look like this:

```
version: "3"
    
services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    command:
      - --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    volumes:
      - ./config/prometheus/prometheus_local.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
        
  loki:
    depends_on:
      - promtail
    image: grafana/loki:latest
    volumes:
      - ./config/loki:/etc/loki
    ports:
      - "3100:3100"
    command: -config.file=/etc/loki/loki-local-config.yaml
        
  promtail:
    image: grafana/promtail:latest
    volumes:
      - .log:/var/log
      - ./config/promtail/promtail-docker-config.yaml:/etc/promtail/config.yml
    command: -config.file=/etc/promtail/config.yml

  grafana:
    depends_on:
      - prometheus
      - loki
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    volumes:
      - ./config/grafana/grafana.ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini
      - ./config/grafana/provisioning:/etc/grafana/provisioning
      - ./config/grafana/dashboards:/etc/grafana/dashboards
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Sample config files for provisioning grafana can be found in the [grafana git repository](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/tree/main/conf/provisioning). Loki provides sample configurations for [itself](https://github.com/grafana/loki/blob/main/cmd/loki/loki-local-config.yaml) and [promtail](https://github.com/grafana/loki/blob/main/clients/cmd/promtail/promtail-local-config.yaml). For Prometheus, see [here](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/main/config/testdata/conf.good.yml).

The official documentaion about installing Grafana with loki can be found [here](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/installation/docker/). There is also [documentation about the Prometheus configuration](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/).

Now you need to configure your application. Enable and expose the endpoint prometheus as described in the [spring boot documention](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html). Configure a log file appender to write the logs to the above configured log directory `.log`.

Your logs will now get collected by Promtail and sent to Loki. Metrics will get stored in Prometheus. You can use PromQL and LogQL to write Grafana queries and render the results in Grafana panels.

With this solution you can add tags to your data that can later be used by grafana.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed reply! I haven't taken a look at the tools you mentioned yet, but do I need them if I just want to plot very simple graphs (for example, get average monthly temperatures from Spring Boot APIs and create a line chart)?

Comment: First of all: You won't need Promtail and Loki for the example you gave. The data is a time series not a log stream. Grafana can render data from time series databases. If you have such data, store it in such a database. If you choose Prometheus, time series collection happens via a pull model over HTTP. That's where Spring Boot Actuator with Micrometer come into place. You could use some other database such as ProstgreSQL to completely avoid the pull model.